# Skype embedded in WPF form

Tags: .net, wpf, skype

From a full screen application, I need to launch another program (Skype in this case). I managed to minimize the full screen application and show Skype, but once finalized, the app does not return to full screen.

Is there a way to launch Skype embedded in my WPF form or something?

The application is running on a public stand (touchscreen), so I don't want users to access the system.

Any ideas or something? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait for a shelled application to end in C#, you just need to follow these instructions. So the method you are using now will work, and you do not need to embed Skype in a WPF form.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305369

Answer (score 0):

There is a Skype API but unfortunately it's being discontinued the end of the year.

That may have been perfect :-(